# collision detection in box2d using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

[image: I]

I have four classes, 
MAIN ,  world  ( which has all the variables ) , Level (code for the enemies and bricks) and Level1

**MAIN class**

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.*;
    import Level;
    import world;

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        public var enemy: enemyMc = new enemyMc();
        public var worldVar:world = new world();
        public var bric:Brick;
        public function Main() {

        var bg: backgroundMc = new backgroundMc();
            addChild(worldVar.m_sprite);
            worldVar.m_sprite.addChild(bg);
            worldVar.m_sprite.addChild(enemy);
            var level = new Level(this, this.stage);

        }
    }

}
```

**world class**

```
package  {
import Box2D.Dynamics.*;
import Box2D.Collision.Shapes.*;
import Box2D.Common.Math.*;
import flash.display.Sprite;



public class world {

        public var gravity: b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2(0, 9.81); // define gravity
        public var createWorld: b2World = new b2World(gravity, true); // add gravity and put to sleep if not active to true
        public var worldScale: int = 30; // convert meters into pixels
        public var enemySphere: b2Body;
        public var timeStep = 1 / 60;
        public var enemyPlacementX = 210; 
        public var enemyPlacementY = 325;
        public var m_sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public function world() {

            addWall(800, 10, 0, 490);  //floor
            addWall(800, 10, 0, -5);// ceiling
            addWall(10, 600, 0, 0); // left
            addWall(10, 600, 800, 0); // right
            // constructor code


        }


        private function addWall(w, h, px, py): void {
            var floorShape: b2PolygonShape = new b2PolygonShape();
            floorShape.SetAsBox(w / worldScale, h / worldScale);
            var floorFixture: b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
            floorFixture.density = 0;
            floorFixture.friction = 10;
            floorFixture.restitution = 0.2;
            floorFixture.shape = floorShape;
            var floorBodyDef: b2BodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
            floorBodyDef.position.Set(px / worldScale, py / worldScale);
            var floor: b2Body = createWorld.CreateBody(floorBodyDef);
            floor.CreateFixture(floorFixture);

        }
   }
}
```

the Level class which gets a stage reference from the Main 
class also has the update function which detects any collisions in a box2D world

```
public function updateWorld(e: Event): void {

        var velIterations: int = 10; // times velocity of objects get updated
        var posIterations: int = 10; // adjusts positions to avoid overlap
        worldVar.createWorld.Step(worldVar.timeStep, velIterations, posIterations); // setup the bodies in the world update speed  10, 10 is a safe number
        for (var currentBody: b2Body = worldVar.createWorld.GetBodyList(); currentBody; currentBody = currentBody.GetNext()) {
            if (currentBody.GetUserData()) {
                currentBody.GetUserData().x = currentBody.GetPosition().x * worldVar.worldScale;
                currentBody.GetUserData().y = currentBody.GetPosition().y * worldVar.worldScale;
                currentBody.GetUserData().rotation = currentBody.GetAngle() * (180 / Math.PI);
            }
        }
        worldVar.createWorld.ClearForces(); // clear forces to let the simulation start again
        worldVar.createWorld.DrawDebugData();

    }
```

it also has another function that creates bricks

```
public function brick(pX: int, pY: int, w: Number, h: Number, stg:Stage): void {

        var bric = new Brick();
        stg.addChild(bric); //assign it to the stage

        bric.x = pX;
        bric.y = pY;
        bric.width = w;
        bric.height = h;

        var polygonShape: b2PolygonShape = new b2PolygonShape();
        var polygonFixture: b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
        polygonShape.SetAsBox(w / 2 / worldVar.worldScale, h / 2 / worldVar.worldScale);
        polygonFixture.shape = polygonShape;
        polygonFixture.density = 1;
        polygonFixture.restitution = 0.5;
        polygonFixture.friction = 0.9;
        var brickbodyDef: b2BodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
        brickbodyDef.type=b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
        brickbodyDef.userData = bric;
        brickbodyDef.position.Set(bric.x / worldVar.worldScale, bric.y / worldVar.worldScale);
        var theBrick: b2Body = worldVar.createWorld.CreateBody(brickbodyDef);
        theBrick.CreateFixture(polygonFixture);


    }
```

the collision detection works well between bricks and enemies until I move the bricks code into another class, then all I see is the bricks laid on the stage in sort of suspended or floating state with no collision detection.

> NOTE:  the collision between the enemy and walls still works even
>   though the walls are also getting created in another class   "world" 
>   not sure what is the issue here.

Here is the Level1 class that does not work

```
package  {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Stage; 
import flash.events.Event;
import Box2D.Dynamics.*;
import Box2D.Collision.*;
import Box2D.Collision.Shapes.*;
import Box2D.Common.Math.*;
import Box2D.Dynamics.Joints.*;
import world;



public class Level1  {
    private var worldVar:world = new world();

    public function Level1() {

    }

    public function brick(pX: int, pY: int, w: Number, h: Number, stg:Stage): void {

        var bric = new Brick();
        stg.addChild(bric);
        bric.x = pX;
        bric.y = pY;
        bric.width = w;
        bric.height = h;

        var polygonShape: b2PolygonShape = new b2PolygonShape();
        var polygonFixture: b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
        polygonShape.SetAsBox(w / 2 / worldVar.worldScale, h / 2 / worldVar.worldScale);
        polygonFixture.shape = polygonShape;
        polygonFixture.density = 1;
        polygonFixture.restitution = 0.5;
        polygonFixture.friction = 0.9;
        var brickbodyDef: b2BodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
        brickbodyDef.type=b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
        brickbodyDef.userData = bric;
        brickbodyDef.position.Set(bric.x / worldVar.worldScale, bric.y / worldVar.worldScale);
        var theBrick: b2Body = worldVar.createWorld.CreateBody(brickbodyDef);
        theBrick.CreateFixture(polygonFixture);         

    }               
}
```

}

Here is the call I am making with in the Level class

```
level1.brick(535, 214, 215, 120, stg);
```

Comment: post the new code that does not work

Comment: To have object in one world reacting with each other they usually need to all be created within one single world not a bunch of different ones like you do.

Comment: if this is true then how come the walls  and enemy are still able to collide even though both of them reside in different classes?  i.e   Level.as  & wall.as class

Comment: Anyone can shed some light on this?